# Angular & Ionic Native Android App

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I am building an angular ionic application.

I need to know, when exporting the application will I get a native java/android code, or will it be exported as web pages?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so on the [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/preface.html) website it says *"...Ionic is an HTML5 mobile app development framework targeted at building hybrid mobile apps. Hybrid apps are essentially small websites running in a browser shell in an app that has access to the native platform layer. Since Ionic is an HTML5 framework, it needs a native wrapper like Cordova or PhoneGap in order to run as a native app."*  So [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/)
is that browser shell or container.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an apk of your project. No web pages or native code will be generated